# Each 2 components are too close in the state diagram in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I've written(copied and pasted) the below code.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning, arrows}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[]
    
        \node[state, initial, accepting] (1) {$1$};
        \node[state, below left of=1] (2) {$2$};
        \node[state, right of=2] (3) {$3$};
    
          \draw (1) edge[above] node{$b$} (2)
                (1) edge[below, bend right, left=0.3] node{$\epsilon$} (3)
                (2) edge[loop left] node{$a$} (2)
                (2) edge[below] node{$a, b$} (3)
                (3) edge[above, bend right, right=0.3] node{$a$} (1); 
    
    \end{tikzpicture}    

\end{document}
```

I got the below image.

[image]

But I expected that the code should generate the below image.

[image]

Quoted the code and the image from [here](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Ekogge/courses/cse30151-fa17/Public/other/tikz_tutorial.pdf) .

What is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use for node placement syntax defined in the `positioning` package or omit this package and increase `node distances to for example 33mm.

In the former case MWE, which for labeling of edges use `quotes` library, is:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, automata, 
                positioning,
                quotes}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 15mm and 15 mm,
every edge/.append style = {draw, -{Straight Barb[scale=0.8]}},
every edge quotes/.style = {auto=right, font=\small, inner sep=2pt}
                        ]
% nodes
\node[state, initial, accepting] (1) {$1$};
\node[state, below left= of 1] (2) {$2$};
\node[state, right= of 2] (3) {$3$};
% arrows
\path   (1) edge["$b$"] (2)
            edge[bend right, "$\epsilon$"] (3)
        (2) edge[loop left,"$a$" '] ()
            edge["{$a, b$}"] (3)
        (3) edge[bend right, "$a$"] (1);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]